# How to make universal remote controller?

Tags: ir, remote-control, testing, induino

I am trying to make simple TV remote using Arduino.

I got [this](http://www.zovirl.com/2008/11/12/building-a-universal-remote-with-an-arduino/) link from Google for making a remote.

Code uploaded perfectly on my device. But all it does is blink a the LED on pin 13.

I hope I have got right code. I have tested it on my TV at home. Is that the correct way of testing it?

IR receiver I have is TSOP-15

P.S. I am completely new to Arduino

The below shown is my Arduino board(induino r3)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've stated in your question, the TSOP-15 is a receiver. That means it detects infrared signals rather than sending them out.

To make a remote control with that code, you need a simple infrared light emitting diode.

It's also important to note that you need to know what signals to send. Different TVs will have different IR codes, depending on the manufacturer. That information can be detected using your receiver module along with your TV's proper remote control.

Comment: By infrared light u mean IR led? Because there is IR LED- 14 on the board

Comment: @Freddy Yes, an IR LED is correct. You would need to modify the code to operate on pin 14 instead of 13 though.